# Build failed while running on the device

Tags: iphone, xcode5

Hi and Thanks in Advance

I moved to Xcode 4.6 to Xcode 5.0. Now I'm running my xcode 4.6 project in xcode 5.0 While executing it on the device (iPhone 4 with iOS 7) through xcode 5.0 I'm getting this error

```
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning the product? (Product -> Clean from the menu bar)

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, 
      Just changed **Build Settings** -> **Architectures** -> **Valid Architectures** to **armv7**